# how to make an element in a Set to be always the 1st element

Tags: java

I have a tree Set which has so many elements in it. I have them in alphabetical order. Can I actually make it to have an element always the 1st element without disturbing the sorted order?

Eg: I want "partnumber" element to be always the 1st element in the set. Can it be done?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: No it cannot, unless your comparator or comparable implementation allows it

Comment: even if Linked HashSet is used ?

Comment: @SilentCoder `LinkedHashSet` **is not** a `TreeSet`.

Comment: Yes, I need them in a report with "partnumber" element to be the first column header.

Comment: This looks like a XY problem; what is it that you want to begin with?

Comment: This is quite a strange question. Can you give us your exact problem specification?

Comment: @GiovanniBotta : I want the "partnumber" element to be always the first element in the Set & rest all elements shall be next to it(sorted alphabetically).

Comment: I get it. What I don't get is why. There is no way to suggest the right data structure if your problem definition is not clear. You realize that a sorted set with an outlier ("partnumber") doesn't really make sense in general. That's why no data structure will do that out of the box. Using a custom comparator is not a good idea because you risk to introduce an odd corner case that might break other parts of the code.

Comment: Let me add, if you __always__ have "partnumber" in your set, and it has a special meaning (like a header), treat it as separate from the set. Corner cases and special cases should be always treated like such. There are really no shortcuts.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta: will note your suggestions too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new `Collection` where you add the desired element first, then add the rest of the elements the way you want/need. For example, you say you have a `TreeSet<String>` which has all your data sorted, then you can use, for example, a `List` and store all the data how you want/need. Here's a kickoff example:

```
TreeSet<String> myTreeSet = ...
//...
//fill the data in treeSet...
//...
List<String> realData = new ArrayList<String>();
realData.add("partnumber");
realData.addAll(myTreeSet);
```

---

In case you go with the `Comparator<String>` implementation (or the class you use), just make sure that `"partnumber"` always is the lesser value, otherwise do the real comparison:

```
class MyPartNumberStringComparator implements Comparator<String>() {
    static final String PART_NUMBER = "partNumber";
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (PART_NUMBER.equals(s1) && s1.equals(s2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (PART_NUMBER.equals(s1)) ? -1 :
            (PART_NUMBER.equals(s2)) ? 1 :
            s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like this is what i was looking for. What if myTreeSet already has partnumber ? It would be a duplicate right?

Comment: @SilentCoder yes, it would be a duplicate, but you can remove it. Anway, I added a `Comparator<String>` implementation that takes `"partNumber"` as the lowest string always.

Comment: right i was going to mention that i could remove it too from the set !! Thanks :)

Comment: It seems like there is a bug with an edge case: if both `s1` and `s2` are "partNumber", then it would incorrectly return `-1` when it should have returned `0`.

Comment: @mattforsythe well, if they are the same, the order won't really matter for this single case...

Comment: It does - for a couple reasons: 1.) the set implementation may decide to use `comare(s1, s2) == 0` when looking for equality.  2.) in the case where they are equal, `compare(s1, s2)` would return `-1`, and `compare(s2, s1)` would also return -1.  This could confuse the algorithm. 3.) the JavaDoc for `Comparator` states that a `Comparator` is "consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S."  The JavaDoc states that bad things can happen in this case.

Comment: @mattforsythe noted after realizing the `get` method won't find it since it doesn't return `0`. Updated the code.

Comment: Yeah, `get` and `contains` behaving poorly was one potential symptom I was thinking of.  The old implementation may also increase the size of the set when you add a duplicate because it doesn't know that it's already there...

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to add a head element to any `Set`.

```
public class HeadSet<T> extends AbstractSet<T> implements Set<T> {
    // The extra item to add at the head.
    final T head;
    // The rest of the items.
    final Set<T> body;

    public HeadSet(T head, Set<T> body) {
        this.head = head;
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        // Iterator starts with the head element and then delegates to the body iterator.
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            private T next = head;
            private Iterator<T> i = body.iterator();

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (next == null && i.hasNext()) {
                    next = i.next();
                }
                return next != null;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                if (hasNext()) {
                    T n = next;
                    next = null;
                    return n;
                } else {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // Size is one more than the size of the body.
        return 1 + body.size();
    }
}

public void test() {
    Set<String> bodySet = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList("One", "Two"));
    Set<String> mySet = new HeadSet("Choose part number ...", bodySet);
    System.out.println(mySet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `LinkedHashSet` and insert each item in exactly the same order that you want them back, or you can provide a custom `Comparator` to your `TreeSet` to sort "normally" (whatever that means for your implementation) but to consider part number as occurring before anything else.

If the objects you are putting into your `TreeSet` implement `Comparable`, then you can override the `compareTo` method to add the special handling for part number.

To implement a `Comparator`, it would look something like this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyDomainClass> {

    @Override
    public int compare(MyDomainClass o1, MyDomainClass o2) {
        // compare the objects here and return a negative integer, zero,
        // or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
        // to, or greater than the second
        return 0;  // stub
    }

}
```

And then when you create your `TreeSet`, you could pass the custom `Comparator` in as an argument to the contructor:

```
TreeSet<MyDomainClass> ts = new TreeSet<MyDomainClass> (new MyComparator());
```

Comment: Thanks, how would the comparator look if i used one?

Comment: @SilentCoder -- show us the comparator you have tried to write.

Comment: @JimN: I really dont know how to write one. And thats why I'm seeking help here.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted my answer please provide some feedback?

Comment: Yes. OP's question is in fact the implementation of the `compare` method or provide another way to solve the problem. And this is not accomplished in your post.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The OP's question mentions nothing about implementing a compare method.  And his comment simply asks what a Comparator would look like (in general).  Being as I don't know what his domain objects actually are, I simply provided the boilerplate for him to fill in the domain logic.

Comment: Still, the core of the answer would be the logic in the `Comparator`, which you haven't even provided.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I disagree.  The core of the answer was 1.) what is the mechanism to change the ordering and 2.) how to jump through the hoops to set it up.  I couldn't possibly answer how to code `compare()` since the OP did not include their domain classes or how they wanted them sorted.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I suppose you could assume from OP's quotes around "partnumber" that they are strings, but 'OP has stated' seems a little overstated.  Given the nature of the request, it also seemed likely that they were more complicated beans that were being sorted on a specific field of type `String`.  For example, a bean that had a `name` and `value`, sorted by `name` and wanted the bean with "partnumber" to appear first.  It's ok - not worth arguing about.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved this before was to have two collections one a List and the other a Sorted Set. When I have to display data I iterate over both these collections in order.

A common use case would be populating the list of countries in a dropdown. 
You want 'None' and 'United States' as the top two items but the rest of the countries you want sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own comparator, it will look something like this:

```
public class comparatorSet implements Comparator<Element type>{

 public int compare(Type e1, Type e2){
  Integer res=0;
  if(e1.equals(firstelement)){
  res=-1;
  }
  else if(e2.equals(firstelement)){
  res=1;
  }
  else{
  res=e1.compareTo(e2);
  }
 return res;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you absolutely need to use a Set, if you use a Max Heap, it will always keep the maximum value at the top, no matter if you insert or remove anything. all you need is an arraylist. Use the comparator like the others have said and you'll be fine.